# wxpython, .env Python-env could not parse statement

Tags: parsing, wxpython, dotenv

I am trying to create a python program to embed a Twitch.tv chat bot that will play a pre-made video when certain things is said in chat or if an event is done (new subscriber, follower etc).
I do have a few issues but will mention the biggest thing that I have so far. I have hidden the secret information. Coder program = Sublime3
There are times in the main file that the quotations fail as there are quotes in the main file. Sorry.
When run, I get an output of :

```
Python-dotenv could not parse statement starting at line 1
Python-dotenv could not parse statement starting at line 2
Python-dotenv could not parse statement starting at line 3
Python-dotenv could not parse statement starting at line 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "frame1.py", line 149, in <module>
    main()
```

File "frame1.py", line 146, in main
FrameClass(None)
File "frame1.py", line 11, in **init**
irc_token = os.environ['TMI_TOKEN']
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\os.py", line 675, in **getitem**
raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'TMI_TOKEN'

Imports:
gui is written in wxpython
python 3.8.5
python-dotenv
twitchio, commands
os

.env

```
TMI_TOKEN='secret code',
CLIENT_ID='secret code',
BOT_NICK='Bot name',
BOT_PREFIX='!',
CHANNEL='Stream channel name'
```

my main code file:

```
#frame1.py
```

import wx, wx.media
import os
from twitchio.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
class FrameClass (wx.Frame):
def **init**(self, parent):
super(FrameClass, self).**init**(parent, title = "Super Bot", size = (750, 400))

```
    irc_token = os.environ['TMI_TOKEN']
    client_id = os.environ['CLIENT_ID']
    nick = os.environ['BOT_NICK']
    prefic = os.environ['BOT_PREFIX']
    initial_channels = os.environ['CHANNEL']



    menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
    fileMenu = wx.Menu()
    connectMenu = wx.Menu()
    helpMenu = wx.Menu()

    openItem = fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_OPEN, 'Open')
    saveItem = fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_SAVE, 'Save As')
    exitItem = fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, 'EXIT')
    helpItem = helpMenu.Append(wx.ID_HELP, 'Help!')

    
    menuBar.Append(fileMenu, '&File')
    menuBar.Append(connectMenu, '&Connect')
    menuBar.Append(helpMenu, '&About')

    
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnOpen, openItem)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.SaveAs, saveItem)       
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.Quit, exitItem)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnHelp, helpItem)

    self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)

    self.CreateStatusBar()
    self.SetStatusText("Welcome to the new Bot!")

    vsplitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self)
    left = LeftPanel(vsplitter)
    right = RightPanel(vsplitter)
    vsplitter.SplitVertically(left, right)
    vsplitter.SetMinimumPaneSize(200)

    bot = ChatBot()
    

    self.Show(True)

def OnOpen(self, event):
    with wx.FileDialog(self, "Open XYZ file", wildcard="XYZ files (*.xyz)|*.xyz", style=wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST) as fileDialog:
        if fileDialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_CANCEL:
            return
    
    pathname = fileDialog.GetPath()
    try:
        with open(pathname, 'r') as file:
            self.doLoadDataOrWhatever(file)
    except IOError:
        wx.LogError("Cannot open file '%s'." % newfile)

def SaveAs(self, event):
    with wx.FileDialog(self, "Save XYZ file", wildcard="XYZ files (*.xyz)|*.xyz", style=wx.FD_SAVE | wx.FD_OVERWRITE_PROMPT) as fileDialog:

        if fileDialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_CANCEL:
            return     # the user changed their mind

        # save the current contents in the file
        pathname = fileDialog.GetPath()
        try:
            with open(pathname, 'w') as file:
                self.doSaveData(file)
        except IOError:
            wx.LogError("Cannot save current data in file '%s'." % pathname)    
    
def Quit(self, e):
    self.Close()

def OnHelp(self, e):
    """Display an help Dialog"""
    wx.MessageBox("This is where future help will be placed. Dont Forget!", "Help", wx.OK|wx.ICON_INFORMATION)
```

class LeftPanel (wx.Panel):
def **init**(self, parent):
wx.Panel.**init**(self, parent = parent)

```
    wx.Button(self, -1, "Test Idle", pos = (10, 10))
```

class RightPanel (wx.Panel):
def **init**(self, parent):
wx.Panel.**init**(self, parent = parent)

```
    self.SetBackgroundColour("grey")

    self.testMedia = wx.media.MediaCtrl(self, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER, szBackend = wx.media.MEDIABACKEND_WMP10)
    self.media = 'C:\\Wiggle_Bot\\Python (Offline)\\JustDoIt.mp4'
    self.testMedia.Bind(wx.media.EVT_MEDIA_LOADED, self.play)
    self.testMedia.SetVolume(0.5)
    if self.testMedia.Load(self.media):
        pass
    else:
        print("Media not found")
        self.quit(None)


def play(self, event):
    self.testMedia.Play()
```

class ChatBot (commands.Bot):
def **init**(self):
super().**init**(os.environ['TMI_TOKEN'], os.environ['CLIENT_ID'], os.environ['BOT_NICK'], os.environ['BOT_PREFIX'], os.environ['CHANNEL'])

```
    # Events don't need decorators when subclassed
    async def event_ready(self):
        print(f'Ready | {self.nick}')

    async def event_message(self, message):
        print(message.content)
        await self.handle_commands(message)

    # Commands use a decorator...
    @commands.command(name='test')
    async def my_command(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send(f'Hello {ctx.author.name}!')
```

def main():
App = wx.App()
FrameClass(None)
App.MainLoop()

main()

Comment: Drop the `,` (comma) at the end of each line in the `.env` file

Comment: @RolfofSaxonythank you so much, such a small thing that the eye can skip over so easily

Comment: It's always the small stuff that stops you in your tracks, frustrating the hell out of you. :)